# Get text occurrences contained in a specified area with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

Is it possible, using *iTextSharp*, get all text occurrences contained in a specified area of ​​a pdf document?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Your coordinates seem to be right and down from the top left corner. Be aware that most often in PDFs coordinates are right and up from the bottom left corner.

Comment: Sorry ... I made a mistake. I wrote 76 instead of 726 ... I made the correction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you need the actual coordinates of the rectangle you marked in Red. On sight, I'd say the x value 144 (2 inches) is probably about right, but it would surprise me if the y value is 76, so you'll have to double check.

Once you have the exact coordinates of the rectangle, you can use iText's text extraction functionality using a `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` as is done in the [ExtractPageContentArea](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=279) example.

For the iTextSharp version of this example, see the C# port of <strike>[the examples of chapter 15](Https://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter15/)</strike>.

```
System.util.RectangleJ rect = new System.util.RectangleJ(70, 80, 420, 500);
RenderFilter[] filter = {new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect)};
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(
        new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1, strategy);
```

Comment: Anyone have any idea how best way to get rectangle coordinates from pdf?. I am too much struggling to get coordinates.

Comment: @RikinPatel See my answer

Answer (score 3):

@BrunoLowagie gives an excellent answer but something I really struggled with was getting the actual coordinates to use. I started out with using Cursor Coordinates from `Adobe Acrobat Pro`.

[image]

From here I could get the coordinate in inches and calculate the DTP point (PostScript points) by multiplying the value with 72.

[image]

[image]

However something was still not right. Looking at the Y value this seemed way off. I then noticed that **Adobe Acrobat counts coordinates in this view from the top left instead of bottom left**. This means that Y needs to be calculated.

I solved this in code like this:

```
var rect = new RectangleJ(GetPostScriptPoints(4.19f), 
    GetPostScriptPoints(GetInverseCoordinateInInches(pdfReader, 1, 1.42f)),
    GetPostScriptPoints(3.5f), GetPostScriptPoints(0.39f));

RenderFilter[] filter = { new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect) };
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(
        new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
var output = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, 1, strategy);

private float GetPostScriptPoints(float inch)
{
    return inch * 72;
}

private float GetInverseCoordinateInInches(PdfReader pdfReader, int pageIndex, float coordinateInInches)
{
    Rectangle mediabox = pdfReader.GetPageSize(pageIndex); 
    return mediabox.Height / 72 - coordinateInInches; 
}
```

[image]

This worked but I think it looks a little messy. I then used the tool `Prepare Form` in Adobe Acrobat Pro and here the Y coordinate showed up correctly when looking at Text Field Properties. It could also convert the box into points right away.

[image]

[image]

This means I could write code like this instead:

```
var rect = new RectangleJ(301.68f, 738f, 252f, 28.08f);

RenderFilter[] filter = { new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect) };
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(
        new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
var output = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, 1, strategy);
```

[image]

This was a lot cleaner and faster so this was the way I choose to do it in the end.

See this answer if you would like to get a value from a specific location for every page in the document:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20959388/3850405

Comment: Thanks @Ogglas, but I don't have Adobe Acrobat Pro

Comment: @RikinPatel You could install the trial version. `Cursor Coordinates` might even be available after trial has ended but I don't think `Prepare Form` will work. https://acrobat.adobe.com/se/sv/free-trial-download.html

Comment: Thanks @Ogglas, but this is not permanent solution, so if you will find any free solution then pls update it.