# Extract text from PDF with Ghostscript - Unknown device: txtwrite

Tags: pdf, text, extract, ghostscript

i'm trying to extract the text from a PDF. I'm working with Ghostscript but when i run the command below

`gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=txtwrite mypdf.pdf`

an error occurs. This one below.

```
Unknown device: txtwrite
Unrecoverable error: undefined in .uninstallpagedevice
Operand stack:
             defaultdevice
```

Any idea about it? Isn't txtwrite a default ghostscript device ?

This is the output of `gs -v`

```
GPL Ghostscript 8.70 (2009-07-31)
```

and that one the OS Version `CentOS release 5.8 (Final)`.

Comment: Try to examine this topic [PDF TEXT Extraction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187250/pdf-text-extraction). I think your GS version doesn't support txtwrite device.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The txtwrite device was introduced to Ghostscript in 9.05 if I remember correctly (current version is 9.06). 8.70 is really quite old and *much* too old to include this device.

Upgrade to a more recent version.