# Looking for recommendation on how to convert PDF into structured format

Tags: python, ruby, parsing, pdf, pdf-parsing

I would like to do some analysis on some properties listed in an upcoming auction. Unfortunately, the city running the auction does not publish the information in a structured format but instead provides a [700+ page PDF](https://ttc.lacounty.gov/Proptax/docs/AuctionBook2013.pdf) of the properties going up for auction.

I'm wondering if the community has any thoughts as to how I can approach parsing said PDF into a structured format for insertion into a db or to create a spreadsheet of the properties.

Here's an image of what each page represents:
[image: Property Guide]

And here's a page that lists some properties:
[image: Sample List of Properties]

I'm comfortable with python and ruby so I don't have any issues scripting up a solution, but because the "columns" and the data in those said columns aren't necessary tied together, it seems like this would be a dubious proposition.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My thought would be to use a pdf to text converter and then parse the text file (assuming that the converter gives you a predictable output format).

Comment: Yea, I tried. There's a ruby project I tried (https://github.com/kitplummer/pdftohtmlr) and it spit out junk.

Comment: What about to text?  That looks like it does html.

Comment: Here's a nice Stack Overflow [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6189489/1322401) that details some pays to get text from a pdf.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski It has a xml output option, but there was no rhyme or reason to the nodes it created.

Comment: Maybe this is best suited for Mechanical Turk...

Comment: Have you tried [pdf-reader](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader)? Does `PDF::Reader.new("foo.pdf").pages.map(&:text)` give you anything useful?

Comment: *it spit out junk.* Have you checked whether text extraction is at all possible from that document?  E.g. By copy&paste from Adobe Reader?

Answer (score 2):

After mucking around with this for 3 hours, I was able to create a parseable XML document from the data. Unfortunately, I was unsuccessful with putting together a completely reusable set of steps that I can use for future auctions publications.

As an aside, I did attempt to call and ask Los Angeles County if they could provide an alternative format of the properties up for auction (excel, etc) and the answer was no. That's government for you.

**Here's a high-level view of my approach:**

- Convert the PDF into a text file using [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)
- Use RegEx foo to clean up and create XML nodes from the data
- Use an XML beautifier / validator to find errors and do cleanup
- Use Python/ruby to add Google Maps Link node, and link to LA County Assessors Map (http://assessormap.co.la.ca.us/mapping/rolldata.asp?ain=APN-GOES_HERE) and
- Convert XML to CSV with Ruby

I used http://xmlbeautifier.com/ as my XML beautifier / validator because it was fast and it gave accurate error reporting, including line numbers.

Use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install Poppler for Mac:

```
brew install poppler
```

After Poppler is installed, you should have access to the pdftotext utility to convert the PDF:

```
pdftotext -layout -f 24 -l 687 AuctionBook2013.pdf auction_book.txt
```

Here's a preview of the XML ([Click here for full XML](http://xml.nopaste.dk/p58862)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listings>
   <item id="1">
      <nsb>536</nsb>
      <minbid>3,422</minbid>
      <apn>2006 003 001</apn>
      <delinquent_year>03</delinquent_year>
      <apn_old>2006 003 001</apn_old>
      <description>LICENSED SURVEYOR'S MAP
          AS PER BK 25 PG 28 OF L S LOT 1              
          BLK 1 ASSESSED TO    J   AND   S
          LIMITED LLC C/O DUNA CSARDAS -
          JULIUS JANCSO LOCATION COUNTY OF
          LOS ANGELES</description>
      <address>VACANT LOT</address>
   </item>
```

**Edit: Adding the Ruby I wrote to convert the XML to a CSV.**

```
require 'rexml/document'
require 'CSV'

class Auction

  def initialize

    f = File.new('AuctionBook2013.xml', 'r')
    doc = REXML::Document.new(f)

    CSV.open("auction.csv", "w+b") do |csv|
      csv << ['id', 'minbid', 'apn', 'delinquent_year', 'apn_old', 'description', 'address']

      doc.elements.each('/listings/item') do |item|
        csv << [item.attributes['id'],
                item.elements['minbid'].text,
                item.elements['apn'].text,
                item.elements['delinquent_year'].text,
                item.elements['apn_old'].text,
                item.elements['description'].text,
                item.elements['address'].text]
      end
    end
  end
end

a = Auction.new()
```

[Link to Final CSV](http://nopaste.dk/p58958)

Answer (score 1):

Convert to text with [Xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) using command `pdftotext`.

I converted your file with the following:

```
pdftottext.exe -layout -f 23 -l 510 AuctionBook2013.pdf AuctionBook2013.txt
```

This conversion leaves text *exactly* in its original layout (due to `-layout` option). Options `-f` and `-l` indicate the first and last page numbers of the range of pages to extract.

From there, parsing should be simple -- a number in column 8 indicates the first line of a record, a blank line ends the record.  Follow the guide for the exact positioning of elements within a record.