# Best tool for text extraction from PDF in Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

I am using Python 3.4 and need to extract all the text from a PDF and then use it for text processing.

All the answers I have seen suggest options for Python 2.7.

I need something in Python 3.4.

Bonson

Comment: Not sure why the down vote. As I mentioned, I checked all available and also on google. The only one I found that can be used with Python 3.4 was in this [xPDF detail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320932/looking-for-recommendation-on-how-to-convert-pdf-into-structured-format?lq=1) all else are of version 2.7. I have found nothing on version 3.4 of Python. Request to also comment when down voted.

Comment: This a good yet blatantly off-topic question. Use [SoftwareRecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) for library recommendations.

Comment: you can try this solution its work good in python 3 [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54936587/7521283)

Comment: [pdfplumber](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber) is the best option. [[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66785646/8321339)]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to install the pypdf package to be able to work with PDFs in Python. pypdf can extract text/images. The text is returned as a Python string. To install it, run `pip install pypdf` from the command line. This module name is case-sensitive so make sure to type all lowercase.

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader('my_file.pdf')
print(len(reader.pages))  # gives '56'
page = reader.pages[9]    #'9' is the page number
page.extract_text()
```

The last statement returns all the text that is available in page 9 of 'my_file.pdf' document.

Comment: Hi Ritesh, By any chance you you know the anser to this question. [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773517/python-based-pdf-mining-and-table-text-processing) .

Comment: Minor correction - think there shoudl be quotations for  "rb" in the open command on line two rather than just rb.

Comment: Furthermore, the pages in pypdf2 are zero-indexed, i.e. `getPage(9)` will get you page #10. Page numbers in the original document are completely ignored by pypdf2.

Comment: One problem with pypdf2 is that in some cases it ignores new line characters which is not really a good thing!

Comment: When importing tables with pypdf2, unfortunately there are no separators between cells. Numbers in adjacent cells get placed together, and there is no way to programmatically recognize what part of the number belongs to which cell. Has anybody figured out a solution for that?

Comment: CAUTION:  a) Not supported in Py3 and b) It ignores entire word if it has an un-parsable unicode ( e.g " )  https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/37 and it is unpredictable as commented by others above. It is a good tool, but not for production code sadly :\(

Comment: 2 years and they haven't fixed this bug
https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/254
I'd prefer to find a package that is properly supported. This one can't handle python 3.

Comment: After looking everywhere, this worked for me! Thank you

Comment: PyPDF2 has improved a lot in 2022. Most comments above are no longer valid.

Answer (score 7):

pdfminer.six ( https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six ) has also been recommended elsewhere and is intended to support Python 3. I can't personally vouch for it though, since it failed during installation MacOS.  (There's an open issue for that and it seems to be a recent problem, so there might be a quick fix.)

Comment: In 2023, I would no longer recommend pdfminer.six. pypdf / tika / PyMuPDF / pdfium2 are way better

Answer (score 3):

Complementing **@Sarah's** answer. PDFMiner is a pretty good choice. I have been using it from quite some time, and until now it works pretty good on extracting the text content from a PDF. What I did is to create a function which uses the [CLI client from pdfminer](https://euske.github.io/pdfminer/#pdf2txt), and then it saves the output into a variable (which I can use later on somewhere else). The Python version I am using is `3.6`, and the function works pretty good and does the required job, so maybe this can work for you:

```
def pdf_to_text(filepath):
    print('Getting text content for {}...'.format(filepath))
    process = subprocess.Popen(['pdf2txt.py', filepath], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

    if process.returncode != 0 or stderr:
        raise OSError('Executing the command for {} caused an error:\nCode: {}\nOutput: {}\nError: {}'.format(filepath, process.returncode, stdout, stderr))

    return stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

You will have to import the subprocess module of course: [`import subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

Answer (score 1):

slate3k is good for extracting text. I've tested it with a few PDF files using Python 3.7.3, and it's a lot more accurate than PyPDF2, for instance. It's a fork of slate, which is a wrapper for PDFMiner. Here's the code I am using:

```
import slate3k as slate

with open('Sample.pdf', 'rb') as f:
    doc = slate.PDF(f)

doc
#prints the full document as a list of strings
#each element of the list is a page in the document

doc[0]
#prints the first page of the document
```

Credit to this comment on GitHub:
https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/437#issuecomment-400491342

Answer (score 0):

```
import pdfreader
pdfFileObj = open('/tmp/Test-test-test.pdf','rb')
viewer = SimplePDFViewer(pdfFileObject)
viewer.navigate(1)
viewer.render()
viewer.canvas.strings
```