# Is there any way to read pdf objects in C# .net

Tags: pdf

I want to read pdf objects with their positions and all styling properties like (text font name, font size , font weight , position) similarly image ( position , height , width ) and other objects in C# .net 
Is there any library paid or free available that can help in achiving this.

P.S I want to read them in form of objects not in form of string or image

Thanks

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241724/extract-images-and-words-with-coordinates-and-sizes-from-pdf/8248457#8248457

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [XFINIUM.PDF](http://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-windows-mono/xfinium-pdf-overview.html) library (developed by the company I work for) supports extraction of page content as a collection of high level objects, text, images and paths. The 'Page Objects' sample shows this feature.

Answer (score 0):

This might help : http://www.pdflib.com/download/tet/
If you already found another solution, please share.

Edit: Also Telerik has a nice PDF control.

Answer (score 0):

The Pdfium.Net SDK  also can help you. Via this API you can get access to a  collection of text, images and other objects. 
Please note I work at the company who develop this API.