# Can we automate pdf using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

Is there any way to get text from PDF pages using selenium/java apart from reading through input file stream?

In my application a report opens in PDF format, I need to get data from it.
When opened in Firefox it shows DOM structure but I wasn't able to locate element using that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract text from a PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650957/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Big NO.Selenium automates browsers,Mock web applications, run tests. What you are asking is not the part of Selenium api. Third party api's are available that doesn't work 100%. check out 
[How to extract text from a PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650957/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf)