# How to find similarity score between two PDFs stored in HDFS

Tags: pdf, comparison, hdfs, artificial-intelligence, cosine-similarity

I have PDFs stored in Hadoop HDFS as unstructured data. I want to find if two PDFs are similar or not and what is the similarity and dissimilarity of these two PDFs.

I am new to this, so it will be very helpful if you can help me with code and its details.

Comment: Removed ML tag, which is not for machine learning.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

If those PDF files are pure text, you can first extract text out of the pdf files with tools in [How to extract text from a PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650957/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf) and calculate some kind of LSH(for instance [simhash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimHash)) of those text.

Then the distance of two files' LSH can be use as their dissimilarity.

Comment: its having image and text both also extraction from hdfs.

Comment: I don't think there is any solution for you out of the box. You need customised code for 1. Read pdf file from hadoop, for example `hadoop fs -cp /data/a.pdf ./` 2. Exact text and image from pdf. 3. Calculate LSH of extracted content.