# How to create a true type font from the PDF document

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I extract embedded fonts from a PDF as valid font files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488042/how-can-i-extract-embedded-fonts-from-a-pdf-as-valid-font-files)

I would like to create a font file (TTF file) from the PDF document. The stream of fontfile2 does not contain CMAP table. How to create a cmap table to make a valid TTF file?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm799.png

Please find the font stream in the above screen shot.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488042/how-can-i-extract-embedded-fonts-from-a-pdf-as-valid-font-files

Answer (score 2):

If it is subsetted it may contain only those glyfs displayed on the PDF page.

Comment: My goal is to rasterize the Pdf, so not a problem for me if it is subsetted. Need to make a valid TTF file which need to draw a string in GDI