# How to extract fonts from PDDocument in PDFBox 2.0.2

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pdfbox

I have seen how to do this in previous versions like below:

[How to extract font styles of text contents using pdfbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939583/how-to-extract-font-styles-of-text-contents-using-pdfbox)

But I think the getFonts() method has been removed now. I want to retrieve a map of texts to fonts (`Map<String, PDFont>`) in the new version of PDFBox but I have no idea how.

Thanks

Kabeer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do this:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load("C:/mydoc3.pdf");
for (int i = 0; i < doc.getNumberOfPages(); ++i)
{
    PDPage page = doc.getPage(i);
    PDResources res = page.getResources();
    for (COSName fontName : res.getFontNames())
    {
        PDFont font = res.getFont(fontName);
        // do stuff with the font
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this but it doesn't have the corresponding string attached to it

Comment: So I am unable to know what text the font is related to

Comment: You asked for a 2.0.2 answer to the question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939583/how-to-extract-font-styles-of-text-contents-using-pdfbox . There is no direct possibility to know what text it is related to; however you can take the PrintTextLocations.java example, the TextPosition object has a getFont() method, i.e. you'd get the font for every extracted character.

Comment: If you mean the font name in the content stream (e.g. "F1"), then do fontName.getName(). To get the real font name, to font.getName().

Comment: Please could you link me to this example? All I require is something that extracts the text and the fonts that relate to the text, not specifically the example I provided. As a side note, do you know why the function above was removed?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of how to retrieve the font names once I have access to the PDFont object :)

Comment: here: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintTextLocations.java The function was removed because of some bigger refactoring effort last year.

Answer (score 3):

```
 PDFMetaData pdfMeta = new PDFMetaData();
 PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("/Users/ban.pdf"));
 PDPage page = document.getPage(0);
 PDResources res = page.getResources();
 for (COSName fontName : res.getFontNames())
{
  PDFont font = res.getFont(fontName);
  pdfMeta.setFontName(font);                    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For PDFBox 2.x the revised code for the answer you are linking to is

```
PDDocument  doc = PDDocument.load("C:/mydoc3.pdf");
for(PDPage page : doc.getPages()){
    // get the names of the fonts in the resources dictionary
    Iterable<COSName> iterable = page.getResources().getFontNames();
    // to get the font for each item call
    // page.getResources().getFont(COSName name);
}
```

Comment: I know how to do this but Iterable<COSName> is not the desired output so this doesn't help me

Comment: @KVohra95 his answer was similar to mine, there is no need to downvote.

Comment: @KVohra95 ok, sorry.

Answer (score -2):

This one is to Extract font of the Pdf file using pdfbox 2.0.6.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
public class PDFFontExtractor {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {  
            PDDocument pddDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\sample1.pdf"));
            for (int i = 0; i < pddDocument.getNumberOfPages(); ++i)
            {
                PDPage page = pddDocument.getPage(i);
                PDResources res = page.getResources();
                for (COSName fontName : res.getFontNames())
                {
                    PDFont font = res.getFont(fontName);
                    System.out.println("FONT :: "+ font);
                }
            } 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does your answer add to Tilman's and Maruan's answers?