# how to find an embedded font from pdf

Tags: fonts

I have a, PDF in an Indian language, Tamil. The creator of the doc has made it in Ghostscript.

When i check the font, it says TTE10CA5BCt00 embedded font. There is no way until now to find the font.

Is there anyway to find what font is used in the doc.

Comment: Those are two different questions. Getting an embedded from from a PDF has tons of answers on Stackoverflow already, so if that's what you really want to do: this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488042/how-can-i-extract-embedded-fonts-from-a-pdf-as-valid-font-files. If you want to know _which font was used_ then the most obvious answer is "why don't you just ask the person that made it"? Email exists, it shouldn't be hard to ask them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I extract embedded fonts from a PDF as valid font files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488042/how-can-i-extract-embedded-fonts-from-a-pdf-as-valid-font-files)