# Placing a subset of a font into a manually created PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I’m creating a PDF using a text editor (manually coding the objects, `xref table`, `trailer`, etc). I want to include a subset of an existing font, for example the characters `ABCD` from the font `LiberationMono-Bold.ttf`, into such a PDF.

The PDF `FontDescriptor` object is expecting a `FontFile2` object.  `FontFile2` itself requires the following:

- `Length` (bytes) of the embedded font program
- `Length1` (bytes) of clear-text portion of the font program
- `stream` containing the font program.

How can I extract these items from a subset of a TrueType font?

Comment: The stream is the subset font. The Length1 is the length of it. The Length is the ordinary Length entry of a stream. If you are not adding any additional compression to the PDF object, Length will be the same as Length1. The question of how to actually produce the subset is vastly more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to tackle the issue but in general you build up a set of glyphs or teardown a full font so there are secondary considerations (apart from is the font licensed to be edited to build up or tear down).

Generally a small set of glyphs is best built up but a 95% subset would be best broken down.

Here are some rough guides on how to program small PDF structures but a Binary  Font is best built using libraries then converted into ascii/ansi compatible text. Certainly I would never attempt to write the necessary font metrics by hand as it's a highly complex component a thus 4 letters is 4 times unlikely to be worth it.

File size for fonts are massive

```
Liberation Mono embedding

    bytes filename

3,259,968 ABACADABA-subset.rtf      = an example of TXT saved with a subset Liberation Mono but has tons of other font garbage.  
  197,577 ABACADABA-PDFAsub-set.pdf = A SubSetFont but with all the baggage that comes with PDF/A compliance !
   23,083 ABACADABA.docx            = should have less garbage and smaller as a zip?
    4,382 ABACADABA.odt             = seems to not have the font included just its name ? my error ?
      211 ABACADABA.rtf             = certainly just text and fontname so not imbedded

    8,411 LiberationMono.pdf        = Lean BUT still bloated XMP with reduced Liberation Mono as subset binary
    6,536 LiberationMonoBinary.pdf  = cLeaner  Liberation Mono as subset binary
   12,080 LiberationMonoAscii.pdf   = cLeaner  Liberation Mono as subset Ascii

    1,957 Binary_Untitled1Font.pdf  = ABCD Liberation Mono subset untitled as binary
    2,910 Ascii_Untitled1Font.pdf   = ABCD Liberation Mono subset untitled as ascii
```

So here is the smallest working file (Binary_Untitled1Font.pdf) that's:

- 9 letters (Abacadaba in CAPS only)
- 780 bytes LiberationMonoABCDregular.TTF
- 1160 bytes = dross for position above on A "4" size page

= 1957 bytes (about 2 KB) as minimal size for a 9 letter message

### So as to Part Answer

What the /Length means its just the after and before stream length,
***NOTE that in both versions below the raw font as decoded length is `/Length1 780` the deflated one is compressed to `/Length 636` whilst the inflated text with line feeds is 1560 + 25 Unix line terminations (note the last line is terminated with > ) = `/Length 1585`.***

```
%PDF-1.4
%ÂµÂ¶

1 0 obj
<</CreationDate(D:20230427)/CreatorTool( )/ModDate(D:20230427)/Producer( )>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<</Pages 3 0 R/Type/Catalog>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<</Count 1/Kids[4 0 R]/Type/Pages>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<</Contents 5 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 595.2 841.92]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<</ExtGState<</GS0 6 0 R>>/Font<</F0 7 0 R>>>>/Type/Page>>
endobj

5 0 obj
<</Length 95>>
stream
q
/GS0 gs
1 0 0 1 56.64 752.16 cm
0 g
BT
.039 Tc /F0 12 Tf 0 1.54 Td [(ABACADABA)] TJ
ET
Q
q
Q

endstream
endobj

6 0 obj
<</ca 1/CA 1/Type/ExtGState>>
endobj

7 0 obj
<</BaseFont/EWGWZO+Untitled1/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/FirstChar 65/FontDescriptor 8 0 R/LastChar 68/Subtype/TrueType/Type/Font/Widths[1323 1121 1136 1105]>>
endobj

8 0 obj
<</Ascent 800/CapHeight 1349/Descent -200/Flags 32/FontBBox[33 -20 1271 1370]/FontFile2 9 0 R/FontName/EWGWZO+Untitled1/ItalicAngle 0/StemV 0/Type/FontDescriptor>>
endobj

9 0 obj
<</Length1 780/Length 636/Filter/FlateDecode>>
stream
xœeR_HSQÿ}w÷î63Ü27“¨]gÓXù 6+ZxIÈ„9¬4°†ÎFi®’ÚÊ"…b‹‚@!    %Ó’Œ¢zz)êÁ—žúKô ”•g}÷®‡ ïðóý~|ç;ßïœ`Ã2Xìè   Ç°)fÒì5§úÜÐ¤Ç¯ØåÃÝ‰®ô³µ8ž(„;×#€TÏœ?ÊDÞ„²Žq?ã²hO_¼ÈJùŒo0^ÓÝÛF†œŒ2¶÷„ã14¢…ñsÆîXïÉ¾ìªÏ˜¸/£Ã|È¨0zàaàúl–ç€9sà<
¬f¿|œº¨èP±Ð,šÅCÕ6* ŽäÍ——^¤ž’xMKé|}˜^NÐy1¨è?ÈÓå³¢•¾›õt®ááv¬†‡Y¥Z=šCs;8P.'Õ”{}ä¨vÖ«VUë—=©ä‚¨ 4}mØun¬ý€ø²»qøÍ;ÚœÊü¦¼L(Hýw"Š.îŸi–¬lm¥G7UŠCbàD\”n¯c5þìœ¼MiC  Phw9«¹n­KÒÜpØ5w¡ê-÷zJU«ØÛ2  †¶^¿&¦ÄñI*¦æ·¼MMÑñPHº-æ“)½þj@\¡#’&Ådàx`çÀ ß¡ËÆºòPÄªìªu7ïv9-öœC‡mdD¼C´…FGŸëÎvE¥Œ¸7=¥èc7Å]R‰_ß.^‚ù¦ŸÞ÷±ó`AÝ–[>ôÛØàÙÜš|U-²*ð_“3Þ£´eçÐ¦ø(/š•þ5•º¡™©{8×Ÿ†.Çà—ƒ†Ž¿VŠvaÆÜ­¢ŒßÎ0É<Áàv Òdr<²ÓÆûßþ Bõ®©
endstream
endobj

xref
0 10
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000109 00000 n 
0000000155 00000 n 
0000000207 00000 n 
0000000349 00000 n 
0000000493 00000 n 
0000000539 00000 n 
0000000712 00000 n 
0000000892 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 10/Info 1 0 R/Root 2 0 R/ID[<0D10EC815A3554E2CF8CE7CA6CE7231C><32346E25D4A60D82FEA82C4F8F900EBA>]>>
startxref
1609
%%EOF
```

And this one should be "WEB SAFE" (Ascii_Untitled1Font.pdf):

[image]

```
%PDF-1.4
%µ¶

1 0 obj
<</CreationDate(D:20230427)/CreatorTool( )/ModDate(D:20230427)/Producer( )>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<</Pages 3 0 R/Type/Catalog>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<</Count 1/Kids[4 0 R]/Type/Pages>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<</Contents 5 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 595.2 841.92]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<</ExtGState<</GS0 6 0 R>>/Font<</F0 7 0 R>>>>/Type/Page>>
endobj

5 0 obj
<</Length 95>>
stream
q
/GS0 gs
1 0 0 1 56.64 752.16 cm
0 g
BT
.039 Tc
/F0 12 Tf
0 1.54 Td
[(ABACADABA)] TJ
ET
Q
q
Q

endstream
endobj

6 0 obj
<</ca 1/CA 1/Type/ExtGState>>
endobj

7 0 obj
<</BaseFont/EWGWZO+Untitled1/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/FirstChar 65/FontDescriptor 8 0 R/LastChar 68/Subtype/TrueType/Type/Font/Widths[1323 1121 1136 1105]>>
endobj

8 0 obj
<</Ascent 800/CapHeight 1349/Descent -200/Flags 32/FontBBox[33 -20 1271 1370]/FontFile2 9 0 R/FontName/EWGWZO+Untitled1/ItalicAngle 0/StemV 0/Type/FontDescriptor>>
endobj

9 0 obj
<</Length1 780/Length 1585/Filter/ASCIIHexDecode>>
stream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>
endstream
endobj

xref
0 10
0000000000 00001 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000109 00000 n 
0000000155 00000 n 
0000000207 00000 n 
0000000349 00000 n 
0000000493 00000 n 
0000000539 00000 n 
0000000712 00000 n 
0000000892 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 10/Info 1 0 R/Root 2 0 R/ID[<0D10EC815A3554E2CF8CE7CA6CE7231C><54E595899FDF1CAFF1E8A2C42A586CF6>]>>
startxref
2562
%%EOF
```

Back to the core question as to how to generate the 780.TTF characters = 4 ABCD characters, that is a really big ask that takes many years to learn from bitter binary experience, so I know it is not "write" as Liberated font ABCD.TTF as I cheated and used a GUI TTF editor, but show me where I am wrong.

### In Summary

The font as stored subset in a PDF is usually (not always) unusable as a font file object (so on extraction is often not a TTF). Here are the two side by side where the trimmed full font of only 4 characters plus TTF header and copyright metadata etc, is reusable after extract but the smaller built from scratch one does not have a usable TTF header etc.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks beyond measure, and very kind of you. I'll digest this over the weekend.

Comment: "takes many years to learn from bitter binary experience" As crafting manual PDFs is supposed to be a hobby for me, not bitter binary experience, I'll stop work here. Thank you very much for your invaluable insight. You have extraordinary knowledge of the PDF spec.

Answer (score 0):

[fontsubset](https://github.com/flashlizi/fontsubset) is a font subset extraction tool. It might help you solve the core question, which is to generate 780.TTF characters = 4 ABCD, as K J's answer said.

For example:

```
fontsubset -s "ABCD" arial.ttf arial-subset.ttf
```

Here is what we will obtain:
[image]

It is not very efficient to yield a subset with a size of 780 bytes, but it is still worth recommending, I think.

We can use `otfinfo` to check the subset font file (thanks to [Kurt Pfeifle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3489099/22143697), and TexLive)

[image]

There is still enough information in this subset file, and maybe it's why the file is not such small.