# Extract fonts from Internet Archive pdf

Tags: linux, pdf, fonts, typography

https://archive.org/details/TheGenevaBible1560/page/n13/mode/2up

I want to extract some of the fonts used in this pdf. It is user-selectable and copy-pasteable so i assume it is possible to extract?

I already tried downloading the pdf and following some of the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488042/how-can-i-extract-embedded-fonts-from-a-pdf-as-valid-font-files) but the problem is that when i download the pdf on my machine, the portion of text in the font that i want to extract (the ancient one) becomes non-selectable, at-least on my pdf viewer (GNOME's Document Viewer) and none of the tools are able to extract any font.

I don't know much about pdf encoding or how this font are being displayed in the browser (are they embedded in the pdf file?) so i don't know how to search for answers.

Comment: It looks like the PDF contains the images of scanned pages overlaid over transcribed text. This means that the font is not actually embedded in the PDF.